# Difference between Promise.resolve and empty Promise Object

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

What is the difference between using Promise below ways.

Way 1:

```
function xyz() {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Way 2.

```
function xyz() {
    return new Promise(() => {});
}
```

So, in a project i was been following they switched the return value of function `xyz` from way 1 to way 2. I am not able to understand why did they switch from way 1 to way 2.

Comment: Way 2 never resolves - it'd be permanently pending - if someone has done that, then they are clueless about how Promises even work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Way 1, you are returning a promise whose state is **fulfilled**.

In Way 2, you are returning a promise whose state is **pending** and it will be pending **forever** because nobody retained either the `resolve()` or `reject()` function references which are the only way to change its state.

I know of no reason to ever do what you have in Way 2 as it's just not useful to have a promise that can never resolve or reject.  These two examples are certainly not the same result.